# A good term for something that sustains itself via a positive feedback loop?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Just for context, I would like to pose the hypothesis that the US dollar is the strongest currency because it is the global reserve currency and is the global reserve currency because it is the strongest currency.

I want to sum this up neatly, and am looking for a term that describes something that sustains itself via a positive feedback loop of this kind and so seems to lack a "real" external cause.

I would make an analogy with circular reasoning, coherentism, and stabilization (in AI, e.g. [The stabilization of environments](https://lukemuehlhauser.com/wp-content/uploads/Hammond-et-al-The-stabilization-of-environments.pdf)).

Comment: **Unstable** is a common engineering term for this type of process.

Comment: @Wayfaring - gtk, but the common language meaning makes me unwilling to use that term for this phenomenon.  The USD is a stable currency; calling it unstable will certainly not get the point across.

Comment: Understood, but there's got to be a negative factor in there somewhere. Perhaps what your looking for is that currency valuation is a product of consensual reality, people's beliefs make it true. Consensual reality doesn't hold in most sciences, but in economics you *must* take what people believe into consideration.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger -- Of course, positive feedback is not necessarily "unstable", if there's a suitable nonlinearity in the feedback loop.

Comment: coherence, not coherentism....I wonder if people read posts thoroughly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd call that ***self-perpetuating***:

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-perpetuating):

> 1. Causing itself to continue to exist.
>      *The committee was **self-perpetuating**: all it did was hold a meeting to decide when the next meeting was, and consume funds to do so.
>
>      It's a **self-perpetuating** error, now that we've made it, we can't fix it without breaking things that depend on it.*

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of a [vicious cycle](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=vicious+cycle) is often called a [virtuous circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuous_circle_and_vicious_circle) or cycle.

From Merriam Webster [virtuous circle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/virtuous+circle):

> A condition in which a favorable circumstance or result gives rise to another that subsequently supports the first. Also called virtuous cycle.

A vicious cycle is a feedback loop that is not desired- negative connotation, in which the result of an action makes things continue to spiral downward. It is the more common phrase. That said, its opposite - in which the feedback tends to be good, is what you are referring too.

For example:

> If you're on the receiving end of generous behaviour, your immediate reaction is to be generous back and you find yourself in a virtuous circle.

Comment: Actually, vicious cycle is Positive feedback, or runaway. It converges to infinity and blows out amplifiers and speakers. It's negative feedback that keeps systems functioning; if it gets too cold, the thermostat turns on the furnace, bringing up the heat until the thermostat turns off the furnace. "Negative feedback control is the primary mechanism for maintaining stability in living (and nonliving) systems, ranging from the smallest cell to the entire biosphere."

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want positive or negative connotations, just something descriptive.

Comment: Yeah, both vicious and virtuous are "positive" feedback, it's just that in the first case that's a bad thing, while in the second case it's good.

Comment: @JohnLawler I wonder if you would come and take a look at my heating system? It needs its regular maintenance and speaks great English, to boot. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Self-sustaining* is the phrase I would use.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, such a currency valuation mechanism is a form of *magical thinking* which is almost bound to end in a *collapsing bubble*.